# get current (code) directory - the location of the cs file

Tags: c#, directory, currentlocation

I'm trying to get my **current** file location.
Every command i run returns the bin folder or the main project folder. I need only the path where i'm located (.cs file).

Comment: There is no *good* way to get this `.cs` file location, because there are no `.cs` files in runtime. In general, it sounds like a bad idea.
As far as I know, the only possible way is to use stack trace or open and process `.pdb` file, but it only works for Debug.

Comment: Side note: while linked (as dup) question answers your exact question it is very likely you need something else as there is not much value in location of CS files (i.e. it makes no sense at all after you copy program to other location/machine)